# how to refresh listbox content onclick or blur event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, listbox

I Need to ask you how I Refresh the listbox content on `listboxfocus` event OR `Onblur` event.

I need if user click on listbox, the content of listbox get refreshed without page refreshed.

Is There is any javascript or jquery which do this.

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you tell what you want to refresh in the listbox? Is it the selected value from the `select`?

Comment: @payal : do you mean refill the dropdown?

Comment: need to refresh the content of listbox....fir ex this values  <option value="audi">Audi</option>

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you mean by refresh, you can attach these events on element and do whatever you want.
better provide id to your dropdown

```
<select id="ride">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

$("#ride").on("click blur", function () {
 $("#ride").html('');
 $("#ride").append('<option value="audi">Audi</option>');
});
```

Comment: my mean is refill the dropdown

Comment: no its not working .I need if i edit audi to bmw and click on listbox  on page then i get updated value in listbox....not to need page refresh....